# ZPL backfeed distance issue, no commans effect feed. Label gets caught

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to limit or stop the backfeed prior to label printing with ZPL

The reason is that when the label backfeeds sometimes it goes too far, past the roller and then doesn't feed at all when the print is attempted.

I've tried:

^XB doesn't make the label come out far enough for a tear
~JSB, ~JSA & ~JSxx  dont appear to have an effect.

I'm working with a GK420d

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS command is the right one and it's compatible with the GK420.
You should use is ~JSx where x is a percent value between 10 and 90, so you can configure the backfeed as you wish.

Also remember to add a ^JUS to save the settings.

So if you want to configure the backfeed at 30%, for instance, you should send:

```
^XA
~JS30
^JUS
^XZ
```

Check [here](https://www.thezcorner.com/printers/languages/zpl/printers-zpl-language-js-command) for more details.